# Extract data from one file and save to another

Tags: regex, awk, sed, text-parsing

I'm running ansible playbook task using shell command to extract data from file based on regex match and save it to another file.

I tried using awk and sed but not able to get the regex working.

```
awk '$NF == "-m.comment.*\""' iptable.txt" > file1.txt
```

```
sed 's/\/.*' iptable.txt > file2.txt
```

I need to save any content from `-m comment` till the double quotes. to file1.txt and remaining content to file2.txt. If the line doesnot have comment field, then it should be saved only to file2.txt.

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW -m comment --comment "Echo Request" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m comment --comment "tcp" -j ACCEPT
```

Expected output:
cat file1.txt

```
-m comment --comment "Echo Request"
-m comment --comment "tcp"
```

cat file2.txt

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Your AWK script has unmatched double quotation mark.

Comment: and your sed script has wrong syntax

Comment: @JUSHJUSH I'm trying to extract till double quotes so I had double quotes as the matching character. Can you pls point me to right syntax for sed?

Comment: wrt `I know regex is right as I tested with regex tester` - proving that a regex works in some online tool ONLY proves that it works in that online tool. That does not mean it'll work in sed, awk or any other command line tool. There's just WAY too many regexp variants, tool variants, extensions, delimiters, options, etc. to think that you can test a regexp in foo and that means it'll work in bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
awk 'match($0,/(.*)(-m.comment.*")(.*)/,a) {
    print a[2] " > foo"
    print a[1] a[3] " > bar"
}' file
-m comment --comment "Echo Request" > foo
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT > bar
```

With any awk:

```
awk 'match($0,/-m.comment.*"/) {
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) " > foo"
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) " > bar"
}' file
```

Just change `" > foo"` to `> "foo"` and ditto for bar to really write to new files.

If that's not exactly what you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Oh and when you wrote:

```
$NF == "-m.comment.*\""
```

There's nothing wrong with `-m.comment.*\"` as a regexp per-se BUT `==` is telling awk to do a literal string comparison, not a regexp comparison.

Given your updated question, just tweak the above to:

```
awk 'match($0,/(.*)(-m.comment.*")(.*)/,a) {
    print a[2] " > foo"
    print a[1] a[3] " > bar"
    next
}
{ print $0 " > bar" }' file
-P INPUT ACCEPT > bar
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT > bar
-m comment --comment "Echo Request" > foo
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT > bar
-m comment --comment "tcp" > foo
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT > bar
```

Comment: Added more information. As I mentioned, I'll be running this using ansible shell module. Extracted content should be saved to another file.

Comment: OK, I tweaked my answer to also print lines that don't contain `comment` to `bar`.

Comment: Thanks Ed. But now ```bar```has only line without ```comment``` and ```foo``` is empty.

Comment: Then either you're trying to use the GNU awk solution but aren't actually running GNU awk or your real input doesn't look like the sample you posted.

Comment: I'm not using GNU awk. But I tweaked it and got it working                            ```awk 'match($0,/(.*)(-m.comment.*")(.*)/,a) {print a[2] > "bar"}' iptable.txt 

awk 'match($0,/(.*)(-m.comment.*")(.*)/,a) {print a[1] a[3]> "bar1"}' iptable.txt 

awk 'match($0,/(.*)(-m.comment.*")(.*)/,a) { next; } { print > "bar2" }' iptable.txt ```

Comment: Only GNU awk has a 3rd arg to match(). If you weren't using GNU awk then you'd be getting a syntax error from the code in your comment. You do NOT need to call awk 3 times, 1 call will do. I updated my answer to show it working.